# Get the inverse of default heat map gradient in Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heat-map

In Google Maps Javascript API for heat maps the default gradient displays red color in areas of higher density and changes to red as intensity decreases. In my application I need to show areas of higher intensity in green and lower intensity in red. I tried printing the default gradient values `heatmap.get('gradient')` only to get 'undefined' value. How can I get the default value of Google Maps API heat map gadient.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who needs it, here's the default gradient:

```
["rgba(102, 255, 0, 0)",
"rgba(102, 255, 0, 1)",
"rgba(147, 255, 0, 1)",
"rgba(193, 255, 0, 1)",
"rgba(238, 255, 0, 1)",
"rgba(244, 227, 0, 1)",
"rgba(249, 198, 0, 1)",
"rgba(255, 170, 0, 1)",
"rgba(255, 113, 0, 1)",
"rgba(255, 57, 0, 1)",
"rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

By the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) it looks that when using the default gradient the value of `heatmap.get('gradient')` is null. I think you'll have to create a new gradient array (like in the example), and when creating the heatmap add

```
   gradient:  gradient_array,
```

to the google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer declaration.

Comment: My question was how to find the default gradient. Any way I found the answer. just had to print `console.log(heapmap)` and then traverse throught the Object printed

Answer (score 0):

just print console.log(heapmap) and then traverse throught the Object printed